# Getting data from column in file

Tags: python

Welcome I manage to download all data from file but now I need only one column for the rest of my program
I tried to do it like so but It didn't work as I intended it will.

```
with open("dane2.txt", "r") as fp:
    samples = [line.strip() for line in fp]
fp.close()
print("CONTENT LEN: %d" % samples.__len__())
for i in range(0,samples.__len__()):
    print(samples[i][0]) #1 column
```

The output I got was:

```
CONTENT LEN: 990
2
2
to 990
```

So I figured that this list is getting all string values I tried to use:

```
[float(i) for i in samples]
```

But it didn't work either so here I'm!

Data in my file looks like this:

```
241.32  241.08  241.72
241.9   241.18  242.11
241.62  241.2   241.83
241.85  241.46  242.02
241.56  241.15  241.8
241.29  240.85  241.54
```

Comment: Can't you use pandas to open your file into a dataframe ?

Comment: My python knowledge is really little so, I don't know what you are suggesting either :')

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Are you just asking how to parse that data? This is an extremely common topic, have you done any research?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you also need to split ('  ') your samples at the spaces. Here's the code:

```
with open("dane2.txt", "r") as fp:
    samples = [line.strip ().split ('  ') for line in fp]
fp.close()
for i in range (len (samples)) : 
    print (samples [i] [0])
```

Or if you want to see all of you data use this one :

```
with open("dane2.txt", "r") as fp:
    samples = [line.strip ().split ('  ') for line in fp]
    print (samples)
fp.close()
for i in range (len (samples)) : 
    print (samples [i] [0], end = '  ')
    print (samples [i] [1], end = '  ')
    print (samples [i] [2])
```

And here's a screenshot of my output :

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: now I only got the bigger string `241.32 241.08 241.72` can't axess anything besides `samples[i][0]`

Comment: `print (samples [i] [1], end = '  ')
IndexError: list index out of range` Like I said above now you got only big string not all the columns in dif index

Comment: Ok I don't know why it's not working so I splited data from columns to other files but thanks for your time!